# Special Relativity - Test Particle inside the Sun's Gravitational Field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, newtonian-gravity

**Question**

[Question Context: Consider the motion of a test particle of (constant) mass $m$ inside the gravitational field produced by the Sun in the context of special relativity.]

Now, the question itself:

Consider the equations of motion for the test particle, which can be written as $\frac{d(m\gamma c)}{dt} = \frac{\vec{v}}{c} \cdot \vec{F}$.

OR

$$\frac{d(m\gamma \vec{v})}{dt} = \vec{F},$$

where $\vec{v}$ is the speed of the test particle, $c$ is the (constant) speed of light, and by definition, $$\gamma \equiv \frac{1}{\sqrt{1- \frac{\vec{v}^2}{c^2}}} .$$

In addition, the gravitational force is given by $$\vec{F} \equiv -\frac{GMm}{r^2} \hat{e}_r$$

where $\hat{e}_r$ is the unit vector in the direction between the Sun (of mass M) and the test particle (of mass $m$).

*Now, integrate the first equation above - that is, $\frac{d(m\gamma c)}{dt} = \frac{\vec{v}}{c} \cdot \vec{F}$ - to find $\gamma$ as a function of $r$, by using the property that $$-\frac{\dot{r}}{r^2} = \frac{d}{dt} \Big(\frac{1}{r}\Big).$$
You may need to introduce a constant of integration. This will be a free parameter of the solution.*

Source: [NOT APPLICABLE]

**Personal Comment**

To put it shortly, I am fairly confused about how to approach this physics problem mathematically.

While I understand that $\gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2 /c^2}}$, I am not sure how this equation is going to ultimately help me find "$\gamma$ as a function of $r$" using the provided "property" in the equation.

Therefore, any amount of help or hints will be greatly appreciated to further aid my learning as well as resolve some of my confusion regarding this question.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103476/discussion-on-question-by-athenian-special-relativity-test-particle-inside-the).

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/527062/2451

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{\vec{v}}{c} \cdot \vec{F} = -GMm(\dot{\vec{r}}.\hat r)/cr^2$

$\vec r = r \hat r \implies\dot{\vec{r}} = \dot r \hat r + r \dot{\hat r}$.

Now, $\dot{\vec{r}}.\hat r = \dot r $,  as $\dot{\hat r}$ turns out to be in $\theta$ direction in plane polar coordinates, therefore does not contribute in your calculation.

Rest is just canceling of d/dt from both the sides adding a constant of integration as, $-GMm\dot r/cr^2 =d/dt(GMm/cr) $

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! However, I admittingly have a hard time understanding your line of reasoning. If possible, do you mind elaborating?

Comment: Do you understand it now?

Comment: Thank you! I more or less understand your thought process. In the end, I solved the problem by making $\frac{d}{dt} (m \gamma c) = \frac{d}{dt} \Big( \frac{GMm}{cr} \Big)$, which ultimately gave me $\gamma (r) = \frac{GM}{c^2} + constant$.

Once again, thank you for your help!