# Special Relativity - Test Particle inside the Sun's Gravitational Field - Differential Equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, differential-equations

**Question**

[Question Context: Consider the motion of a test particle of (constant) mass $m$ inside the gravitational field produced by the Sun in the context of special relativity.

In addition, consider the equations of motion for the test particle, which can be written as $$\frac{d(m\gamma c)}{dt} = \frac{\vec{v}}{c} \cdot \vec{F}$$

OR

$$\frac{d(m\gamma \vec{v})}{dt} = \vec{F},$$

where $\vec{v}$ is the speed of the test particle, $c$ is the (constant) speed of light, and by definition, $$\gamma \equiv \frac{1}{\sqrt{1- \frac{\vec{v}^2}{c^2}}} .$$

In addition, the gravitational force is given by $$\vec{F} \equiv -\frac{GMm}{r^2} \hat{e}_r$$

where $\hat{e}_r$ is the unit vector in the direction between the Sun (of mass $M$) and the test particle (of mass $m$).]

**The Question Itself**

Solve the previously found differential equation
$$\frac{d^2u}{d\theta^2} + u \bigg( 1- \frac{G^2 M^2}{\ell^2 c^2} \bigg) - \frac{GMd}{\ell^2} = 0$$
for the trajectory, i.e. find the solution for $u(θ)$ (for all $θ$). What kind of trajectories do you find?

Source: [NOT APPLICABLE]

---

**Personal Comment**

Perhaps it's just me, however, I can't seem to solve this differential equation in a clean manner. For some reason, I always get a ton of constants and I feel like I am doing something wrong. With that in mind, any assistance, hints, or comments to help me toward the right answer would be much appreciated. Thank you for reading!

Comment: What if you called $$u\left(1 - \frac{G^2 M^2}{\mathcal{l}^2 c^2}\right) - \frac{GMd}{\mathcal{l}^2} = z.$$ What would be the differential equation for $z$?

Comment: This question appears to be very similar to your earlier question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/525169/123208

Comment: You should not get “a ton of constants” from a 2nd-order ODE. You should get two.

Comment: @PM2Ring, Indeed, it's similar simply because this is considered as a "follow up" question.

Comment: @G.Smith, Hmmm, thanks for the clarification. However, considering that both $d$ and $\ell$ are constants already in the equation, that would make a tally of four constants, right?

Comment: Well, $G$ and $M$ are there too. I was talking about constants of integration, not constants in the ODE to begin with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re-write for legibility:
$$u''(\theta)+\alpha u(\theta)-\beta=0$$
Make a substitution:
$$y=\alpha u(\theta)-\beta$$
So:
$$y'=\alpha u'$$
And:
$$y''=\alpha u''$$
$$\Rightarrow u''=\frac{y''}{\alpha}$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{y''}{\alpha}+y=0$$
$$y''(\theta)+\alpha y(\theta)=0$$

Which is the classic ODE of the SHM. Solve and back-substitute. Don't neglect the BCs!

Comment: Out of curiosity, would taking the ansatz: $u = a(1+e cos(bt))$ for some $a$, $b$ and substitute it back to the differential work in acquiring the solution?

Comment: When doing so, a friend said I should get $u = \frac{GMd}{\ell^2} \bigg(1- \frac{G^2 M^2}{\ell^2 c^2}\bigg)^{-1}  \bigg(1+ e cos\bigg( \big(1- \frac{G^2 M^2}{\ell^2 c^2} \big) \theta \bigg) \bigg)$ as the answer ...

Comment: Not sure on both counts. It takes a while to work those out!